# How to use ant.resourcelist in groovy-script/gradle

Tags: grails, groovy, ant, gradle

I have a task - to remove files from the list, which is stored in a file.
For this I want to use Groovy script.
In Ant I have no problem using the following target:

```
<delete failonerror="false" verbose="true">
        <resourcelist >
            <file file="/path/to/file"/>
        </resourcelist>
</delete>
```

But in Groovy script is causing the error:

```
ant.delete(
        failonerror: "false",
        verbose: "true",
        ant.resourcelist(
                ant.file(
                    file: "/path/to/file"
                )
        )
)
```

Error:

```
The <resourcelist> type doesn't support nested text data ("/path/to/file").
```

How to configure Groovy skipt to remove files from the list located in the another file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use a Delete task? https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html

Comment: Everything I tried - contains many of a custom code. Can you please give the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax, has to be (here using the groovy task) :

```
<project>

<taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

<groovy>
  ant.delete(failonerror: false, verbose: true) {
   resourcelist {
    file(file: '/path/to/file')
   }
  }
</groovy>

</project>
```

-- Edit after comment --
When using a groovy file you have to use :

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
 ant.delete(failonerror: false, verbose: true) {
  resourcelist {
   file(file: '/path/to/file')
  }
 }
```

Comment: When i use this from groovy-script - i get error:  Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: {file=/path/to/file}.
I try add ant. to file, then output dont show anything

Comment: Thank you! In gradle must be used: 'ant.file(file: 'remove.txt')'